# Strange behavior of dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic tab in which i want to show a HTML DIV.Now in the first click i am able to see the HTML DIV inside the dynamic tab .But if closed once and reopened again by clicking Hyperlink meant to open this Tab , I am not to get it this time.. I dont know what is happening here ..

Here is the code..

```
       function addTab(title) {
        if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)) {
            $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
        } else {

            if (title == "Check in List") {

                var content = $("#checkinuserform");

            }
            else {

                var content = '<p>Hii</p>';

            }

            $('#tt').tabs('add', {
                title: title,
                content: content,
                closable: true
            });
        }
    }
```

In the code `checkinuserform` is the HTML DIV id..
Please help me ..Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to clone the div:

```
var content = $("#checkinuserform").clone();
```

Comment: It Worked ..Thanks a lot ..I have a query that If i want to add dynamic data from database every time user clicks this Dynamic tab Hyperlink ,,Will the HTML Div be able to load the dynamic data from database?

Comment: I would say yes, the problem were, that you grab the div, and move it to the tab, when tab content is deletet, the div is gone, with clone you let it where it is, and can grab it again...